# Is there a way to control appearance of Bot Menu Button?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

The somewhat-new feature of [bot menu button](https://telegram.org/blog/animated-backgrounds#bot-menu) now dissapeared from my and other bots I used from my macOS client, presumably after latest mac Telegram update, version `8.1 (221723) Stable`. Looking at some screenshots I did, menu button was there as of 14th September. Still shows on the Android phone. [Link to two screenshots showing the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Pemn.jpg)

Google and SO searches do not address the question:

**Can developers manage the appearance of the menu button instead of attachment button?** Where did it go?

My bot heavily depends on the button and doesn't give any hints to the commands in the text. Did they silently disable it for desktop client? Any insight appreciated.

Comment: Consider referring the [release notes](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api)?

Comment: @DebarghaRoy Yep looked it up. Last release change is dated June 25, 2021

Comment: Maybe check with the Mac Developer Community?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can developers manage the appearance of the **bot-menu** button?

**Yes**, by using the [`setMyCommands`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setmycommands) method, you can control the command listed in the menu.

The [`command scope`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#determining-list-of-commands) is used to determine the list of commands for a particular user viewing the bot menu

---

> Can developers manage the appearance of the **attachment-menu** button?

**No**, the [attachment button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dbbg.png) is handled by the Telegram Client.
Therefore it's not possible to manually show/hide the button.

There isn't a complete list of clients which will show the button, however

- *Telegram Desktop 3.1 client*
- *Telegram 8.1 (221723) AppStore client*

Both show the original design, with the `/` and attachment button.

The Android version does not show the button.

Comment: Thanks but it looks like I didn't ask a clear question. I'm not interested in *contents* of the menu, I'm interested in menu button itself, which is now absent in my macOS Telegram client, version 8.1 (221723) Stable

Comment: Ahh, I've added a line to make this clear. As of now, there no way to force this. It's depended on the client you're using.